# Consent библиотека для пользователей из европейского союза

Tags: android, admob

Кто интегрировал consent для европейских стран? У меня после выбора не персональной рекламы, реклама вообще не отображается. Это нормально? Или надо еще менять код в самих рекламных блоках?

```
public class GDPRHelper {

private Context context;
private ConsentForm consentForm;

public GDPRHelper(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    initConsent();
}


private void initConsent() {

    ConsentInformation consentInformation = ConsentInformation.getInstance(context);
    consentInformation.requestConsentInfoUpdate(new String[]{context.getString(R.string.admob_id)}, new ConsentInfoUpdateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onConsentInfoUpdated(ConsentStatus consentStatus) {

            // User's consent status successfully updated. Display the consent form if Consent Status is UNKNOWN

            boolean inEEA = ConsentInformation.getInstance(context).isRequestLocationInEeaOrUnknown();

            if (inEEA) {
                if (consentStatus == ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED) {

                    saveConsentStatusNP();

                } else if (consentStatus == ConsentStatus.PERSONALIZED) {

                } else {
                    displayConsentForm();
                }
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailedToUpdateConsentInfo(String errorDescription) {

            // Consent form error.
        }
    });
}

private void displayConsentForm() {

    consentForm = new ConsentForm.Builder(context, getAppsPrivacyPolicy())
            .withListener(new ConsentFormListener() {
                @Override
                public void onConsentFormLoaded() {
                    // Display Consent Form When Its Loaded
                    consentForm.show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormOpened() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormClosed(ConsentStatus consentStatus, Boolean userPrefersAdFree) {
                    // Consent form is closed. From this method you can decided to display PERSONLIZED ads or NON-PERSONALIZED ads based                on consentStatus.
                    if (consentStatus == ConsentStatus.NON_PERSONALIZED) {
                        saveConsentStatusNP();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onConsentFormError(String errorDescription) {
                    // Consent form error.

                }
            })
            .withPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .withNonPersonalizedAdsOption()
            .build();
    consentForm.load();
}

private URL getAppsPrivacyPolicy() {
    URL mUrl = null;
    try {
        mUrl = new URL(context.getString(R.string.privacy_policy_url));
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return mUrl;
}

private void saveConsentStatusNP() {
    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putString("npa", "1");

    AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
            .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, extras)
            .build();
}
}
```

Comment: Что, совсем никто не реализовывал? С мая месяца нарушаем закон получается. Интересно, гугл будет проверять приложения на наличие реализации соглашения?

Comment: Проблема все еще актуальна. Не проходите мимо! В другой теме та же проблема и нет никакого ответа на вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56423585/failed-to-load-admob-ad-errror3-error-code-no-fill